# Building association for rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a user that has_one :company. I need to build the company's attributes via the strong parameters, but i'm running into a `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`. My code looks like this:

```
    def create
     @user = User.new(permitted_user_params)
     @user.build_company(params[:user][:company_attributes])
    end

    def permitted_user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, 
                              company_attributes: [:name, :bio])
    end
```

My company.rb looks like

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end
```

My user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :company
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
end
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Firstly, you shouldn't need to do this part: `@user.build_company...` the `accepts_nested_attributes` should do that for you.

Comment: Secondly: can you look at your logs (either from the console/terminal or `logs/development.log`) and give us the full message of the `ForbiddenAttributesError` ? which attributes are being rejected exactly? in fact - can you go to your logfiles and watch as you submit the form, and copy every line of output that occurs after you hit submit? then edit your question and paste it in for us - that will help us narrow down what exactly is going wrong for you :)

Comment: Thanks, Taryn. It was as simple as removing the @user.build_company.

Comment: hehe - sometimes it's the simple things. I'll add it as an answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you shouldn't need to do this part:

```
 @user.build_company(params[:user][:company_attributes])
```

that part is implied in `accepts_nested_attributes` and it should do that for you, as long as you have you `permit/require` set up correctly (which you do).